# Flume Source Type

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, flume

I have a sensor that emits data for every 5 seconds. I am trying to insert the generated data in to my hadoop hdfs. For this purpose, I have chosen flume for real time collection of data. 
I am getting confused, to choose which type of source i need to choose to receive data. 
There is an authentication and we need to provide user id and password to get the data. Which source allows me to give username and password

Comment: Is this pull or push based? Does your sensor outputs to a file actively or stores data somehow and you need to retrieve it through a request? The authentication is needed to pull the results from the sensor or you want authentication to push things into DFS ?

Comment: Its pull based, Sensor outputs are stored in a cloud and we are trying to pull it into our cluster in real time. There is an authentication to access the data that is stored in cloud and now getting issues when trying to get the data in our cluster through flume.